# How to allow the reply link to remain on the comment form after I have reached my 10 nested comment limit?

Tags: comments, comment-form

Is there a way to allow the reply link to remain on the comment form after I have reached my 10 nested comment limit?

I don't necessarily need nested comments I just need the reply link to be always available as I'm using a plugin that only sends out email notifications on a comment "reply".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to modify the `max depth`, you could use the `thread_comments_depth_max` filter:

```
/**
 * Set max comments depth to 15 on the discussion settings page
 */
add_filter( 'thread_comments_depth_max', function( $max )
{
    return 15;
} );
```

then the dropdown on the *discussion settings* page will show the range 1 - 15.

But I can imagine very deep comment threads would be harder to read.

Another approach would be to override the `thread_comments_depth` option value on the front-end:

```
/**
 * Set max comments depth to 15 on the front-end
 */
add_filter( 'option_thread_comments_depth', function( $val )
{
    if( ! is_admin() )
        $val = 15;

    return $val;
} );
```

The reason why the reply links don't show for depths greater than the max depth is this part:

```
if ( 0 == $args['depth'] || $args['max_depth'] <= $args['depth'] ) {
    return;
}
```

within the `get_comment_reply_link()` function.

It's not possible to use the `comment_reply_link_args` filter, because it's applied after the depth check, for some reason.

Comment: "But I can imagine very deep comment threads would be harder to read."... couldn't that be solved with un-nested css styling?

Comment: yes, that css might be a workaround. If the comment_reply_link_args would be above the depth check, then I think we could have a more dynamic depth and even change the max_depth per comment.  @Pete