# Removing the limit on the number of nested comments

Tags: comments

Does anyone have a solution for removing the limit on nested comments?

I've found on a site I maintain that there are a few comments where no "Reply" button is visible and since worked out that this is due to the mxa nested comments being reached.   It's already set the max setting possible in the WordPress settings (in the discussions settings page) which is 10.

There was a plugin that did this (https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/infinite-comment-replies/) but it's not maintained and don't even want to try it.   Has anyone found a proper fix to extend / remove this limit?

Comment: the plugin looks fine, however have you tried just setting it to more than 10? Either by adding a new option to the dropdown via the dev tools, or by directly setting the option via `update_option(...` or the `options.php` page? ( `thread_comments_depth` is the option name )

Comment: Ah great, just updating thread_comments_depth worked perfectly!  Feel free to write an answer if you want some points.

Comment: This question might help... [https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/215575/how-to-allow-the-reply-link-to-remain-on-the-comment-form-after-i-have-reached-m](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/215575/how-to-allow-the-reply-link-to-remain-on-the-comment-form-after-i-have-reached-m)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`thread_comments_depth` is the option you need to change, and while the dropdown gives you several predefined values, the option can store any value.

So if you use the dev tools to adjust the dropdown to add a 9999 option, you can set it to a max of 9999 nested comments, or more even. You can also set the option directly via `update_option`, or with the `options.php` admin page that lists all options.